# Using TeXShop, Typeset calls biber with pdflatexmk but not xelatex, and xelatex throws CPU type error

Tags: xetex, biber, texshop

Using TeXShop Version 4.44 (4.44) on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5, invoking Typeset from the editor window calls biber with pdflatexmk but not xelatex.  In addition, xelatex is throwing this error at the top of the console:

```
ps: Invalid (zero-length) process id
/sw/bin/start-session-bus.sh: line 21: /sw/bin/dbus-launch: Bad CPU type in executable
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

Here are MWEs.

This MWE works, but I don't get to have cites, plus it throws the above bad CPU error:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
lots words
\end{document}
```

This MWE works but I don't get to have xelatex:

```
% !TEX encoding = MacOSRoman
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../bibs/dumbbibs.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
lots words~\autocite[][]{Fuetal:2018,Merkeletal:2010}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title={References}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

With this MWE the console reports that it refuses to call biber.  I've tried typing biber MWE.bcf in the console but it just highlights that text and nothing happens.  Typesetting will work fine with this one as long as I don't mess with the cites, so that it needs to call biber:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../bibs/dumbbibs.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
lots words~\autocite[][]{Fuetal:2018,Merkeletal:2010}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title={References}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

I get this complaint at the console when typeset the above (in addition to the bad CPU complaint at the start of the run):

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                MWE
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I need to use xelatex in order to use fontspec.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit added to include troubleshooting information related to the bad CPU complaint:

~ >echo $PATH /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:~/local/bin:/usr/games

~ >which xelatex /usr/local/bin/xelatex
~ >which pdflatex /usr/local/bin/pdflatex

TexShop Engine Path settings: (pdf) TeX /Library/TeX/texbin, Distiller (ghostscript) /usr/local/bin. In TeX Live Utility it lists TeXLive-2019 and -2018, with 2019 chosen as default.

By the way, TeXLive just now had me do what it called an important infrastructure type update, so I tested xelatex but still get the CPU error: ps: Invalid (zero-length) process id /sw/bin/start-session-bus.sh: line 21: /sw/bin/dbus-launch: Bad CPU type in executable This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode

Where are you setting your PATH? What does which biber return? What does ls -al /usr/local/bin/pdflatex return?

You are NOT using the TeX Live 2019 distribution since you have interfering other versions of things. Xetex as included with TeX Live 2019 doesn't use anything in /sw.

~ >which biber /Library/TeX/texbin/biber

> ls -al /usr/local/bin/pdflatex 0 lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 59 Nov 16 2018 /usr/local/bin/pdflatex@ -> /Applications/MiKTeX Console.app/Contents/bin/miktex-pdftex

Interestingly, I just noticed this message at the top of the terminal window: Last login: Sat Jan 4 22:07:05 on ttys001 ps: Invalid (zero-length) process id /sw/bin/start-session-bus.sh: line 21: /sw/bin/dbus-launch: Bad CPU type in executable

In Terminal/preferences it says Window group is bash, and Shells open with Command /bin/bash.

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Here is .bash_profile:

## .bash_profile

## Get the fink aliases and functions

if [ -f /sw/bin/init.sh ]; then
        . /sw/bin/init.sh
fi

## Get the aliases and functions

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
stty stop ^S intr ^C erase ^?

## disp

## edisp

date

## fortune

## User specific environment and startup programs

ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
USERNAME="a_user"

export USERNAME ENV PATH

## export USERNAME ENV

function pdfman()
  {
  man -t $@ | pstopdf -i -o /tmp/$1.pdf && open /tmp/$1.pdf
  }

## Setting PATH for Python 2.7

## The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Here is /sw/bin/init.sh:

## init.sh

#

## to use the Fink hierarchy, put the following in your .profile:

#

## . /sw/bin/init.sh

#

#

## Fink - a package manager that downloads source and installs it

## Copyright (c) 2001 Christoph Pfisterer

## Copyright (c) 2001-2004 The Fink Team

#

## This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or

## modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License

## as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2

## of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

#

## This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,

## but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of

## MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the

## GNU General Public License for more details.

#

## You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License

## along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software

## Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.

#

## define append_path and prepend_path to add directory paths, e.g. PATH, MANPATH.

## add to end of path

append_path()
{
  if ! eval test -z "\"\${$1##*:$2:*}\"" -o -z "\"\${$1%%*:$2}\"" -o -z "\"\${$1##$2:*}\"" -o -z "\"\${$1##$2}\"" ; then
    eval "$1=\$$1:$2"
  fi
}

## add to front of path

prepend_path()
{
  if ! eval test -z "\"\${$1##*:$2:*}\"" -o -z "\"\${$1%%*:$2}\"" -o -z "\"\${$1##$2:*}\"" -o -z "\"\${$1##$2}\"" ; then
    eval "$1=$2:\$$1"
  fi
}

## setup fink related paths. we assume that the fink directories exists.

if [ -z "$PATH" ]; then
  PATH=/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
else
  prepend_path PATH /sw/bin:/sw/sbin
fi
export PATH

osMajorVer=`uname -r | cut -d. -f1`
osMinorVer=`uname -r | cut -d. -f2`
if [ -z "$MANPATH" ]; then
  if [ $osMajorVer -gt 7 ]; then
    MANPATH=`/usr/bin/manpath`
  else
    MANPATH=`/usr/bin/manpath -q`
  fi
fi
prepend_path MANPATH /sw/share/man
perlversion=`/usr/bin/perl -e 'printf("%vd\n", $^V)'`
append_path MANPATH /sw/lib/perl5/$perlversion/man
export MANPATH

if [ -z "$INFOPATH" ]; then
  INFOPATH=/sw/share/info:/sw/info:/usr/share/info
else
  prepend_path INFOPATH /sw/share/info:/sw/info
fi
export INFOPATH

if [ -r /sw/share/java/classpath ]; then
  if [ -z "$CLASSPATH" ]; then
    CLASSPATH=`cat /sw/share/java/classpath`:.
  else
    add2classpath=`cat /sw/share/java/classpath`
    prepend_path CLASSPATH $add2classpath
  fi
  export CLASSPATH
fi

if [ -z "$PERL5LIB" ]; then
  PERL5LIB=/sw/lib/perl5:/sw/lib/perl5/darwin
else
  prepend_path PERL5LIB /sw/lib/perl5:/sw/lib/perl5/darwin
fi
export PERL5LIB

## Add X11 paths (but only if the directories are readable)

if [ -r /usr/X11R6/bin ]; then
    append_path PATH /usr/X11R6/bin
    export PATH
fi
if [ -r /usr/X11R6/man ]; then
    append_path MANPATH /usr/X11R6/man
    export MANPATH
fi

## On Mac OS X 10.4.{x|x<3} there is a dyld bug (rdar://problem/4139432)

## where a library will not load if a library with a matching basename

## is already loaded from one of the system paths,

## the workaround is to set DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH to :

if [ -z "$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
  if [ $osMajorVer -eq 8 -a $osMinorVer -lt 3 ]; then
    DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=:
    export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
  fi
fi

PROXYHTTP=`grep ProxyHTTP /sw/etc/fink.conf | grep -v "#" | cut -d " " -f2`

if [ "$PROXYHTTP" != "" ]; then
  HTTP_PROXY=$PROXYHTTP
  http_proxy=$PROXYHTTP

export HTTP_PROXY http_proxy
fi

PROXYFTP=`grep ProxyFTP /sw/etc/fink.conf | grep -v "#" | cut -d " " -f2`

if [ "$PROXYFTP" != "" ]; then
  FTP_PROXY=$PROXYFTP
  ftp_proxy=$PROXYFTP

export FTP_PROXY ftp_proxy
fi

## read per-package scripts from /sw/etc/profile.d

if [ -d /sw/etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /sw/etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r $i -a -x $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

## eof

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Here is ~/.bashrc:

## .bashrc

## User specific aliases and functions

## Source global definitions

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

## bash settings

if [ -f ~/.bash_alias ]; then
       source ~/.bash_alias
fi

## set filec

## unset addsuffix

## set histlit

## set pushdtohome

## set rmstar

## set prompt="`hostname` !% "

## umask 022

## use emacs editing at standard input

set -o emacs

## for Japanese linux

## export XMODIFIERS="@im=kinput2"

## standard input prompt

## PS1='\h \w >'

PS1='\u@\h:\w >'

## secondary prompt string

PS2='>'

PS4='$0 line $LINENO: '

## Tell X where to find general-purpose settings

## XENVIRONMENT=~/.Xdefaults

## export XENVIRONMENT

## setenv MANPATH /usr/catman:/usr/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/catman

## setenv MANPAGER 'pg -p "( Page %d ):" -n'

## setenv DISPLAY e694919.ds.boeing.com:0.0

## setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/

## MANPATH=/usr/man:/usr/local/man:

## export MANPATH

## INFOPATH=/usr/info:/usr/local/info/

## export INFOPATH

## RPASHOMEPATH=.:/data1/users/bmaster/rpasview/master

## export RPASHOMEPATH

## setenv TCL_LIBRARY /usr/cygnus/y/lib/tcl7.5

## setenv TK_LIBRARY /usr/cygnus/y/lib/tk4.1

## DICTSTEG=/usr/local/etc/DeLaTerreALaLune

## export DICTSTEG

## SM_SAVE_DIR=/home/beamis

## export SM_SAVE_DIR

## About path/PATH:

## The order is important to not confuse /usr/bsd/rsh and /bin/rsh.

## Seting 'path' also sets $PATH in the environment for csh users.

## The reverse is not true!

## Dot should be last.  This helps to keep a trojan horse ls or the like

## program from being found first.  Superuser should not have '.' in his path.

## Example from 4Dgifts:

## set path=( $HOME/bin ~/iristools/imgtools ~/iristools/tools /usr/bin /usr/bin/X11 /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bsd /bin /etc /usr/etc /usr/demos/bin . )

## set path = ($path /usr/demos/bin /usr/local/bin)

## If desired directories are not in path, add them.

## Note: egrep returns 0 if found.

echo $PATH | egrep '/usr/local/bin' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":/usr/local/bin"
fi
echo $PATH | egrep '~/local/bin' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":~/local/bin"
fi
echo $PATH | egrep '/bin' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":/bin"
fi
echo $PATH | egrep '/sbin' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":/sbin"
fi
echo $PATH | egrep '/usr/bin' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":/usr/bin"
fi
echo $PATH | egrep '/usr/sbin' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":/usr/sbin"
fi
echo $PATH | egrep '/usr/games' >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  PATH=$PATH":/usr/games"
fi

MANPAGER=less
export MANPAGER
EDITOR=/usr/bin/xemacs
export EDITOR

## set new file protection in users (4/21/98 - root)

umask 027

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Here is /etc/bashrc:

## System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '

## Make bash check its window size after a process completes

shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
I don't think there's anything interesting in .bash_alias, but I can show if you like.

Comment: The conversation in comments has stopped a week ago, but for preserving and continuing this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103399/discussion-on-question-by-mr-gold-using-texshop-typeset-calls-biber-with-pdfla). Thanks!